# Two Digit Years with NSDateFormatter not working

Tags: cocoa, nsdateformatter, nstextfield, nsformatter

I have a 10.4 style date formatter applied to an NSTextFieldCell. I call setTwoDigitStartDate: (tried with both the epoch date and the "reference" date) but when I type in a date with a two digit year it sets the year to 0009 instead of 2009.

Header:

```
IBOutlet NSTextFieldCell *transactionDateField; // outlet *IS* set correctly in IB
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:0];
    //NSDate *startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormat setTwoDigitStartDate:startDate];
    [dateFormat setLenient:YES]; // tried with & without this
    [transactionDateField setFormatter:dateFormat];
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` to this `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`

Comment: It turns out that setTwoDigitStartDate: only works with date formats with a two digit year (NSDateFormatterShortStyle being one such format). I thought you'd be able to control the input of abbreviated long dates with this convenience method but alas you can not.